# SQL Server Group By clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is sample output of D009022 table.

```
LBrCode PrdAcctId
1       20060000000001420000000100000000
1       20060003002891900000000100000000
1       20060004001110490000000100000000
```

I'm using this query to calculate total per product.

```
SELECT 
    A.LBrCode AS BranchCode, 
    (SELECT B.Name FROM D001003 B WHERE A.LBrCode = B.PBrCode) AS BranchName,
    substring(A.PrdAcctId,1,8) AS ProductCode,
    (CASE WHEN substring(A.PrdAcctId,1,8)='20060000' 
            THEN count(substring(A.PrdAcctId,1,8)) 
     END) AS Miulasi,
    (CASE WHEN substring(A.PrdAcctId,1,8)='20060001' 
            THEN count(substring(A.PrdAcctId,1,8)) 
     END) AS Piripun,
    (CASE WHEN substring(A.PrdAcctId,1,8)='20060002' 
            THEN count(substring(A.PrdAcctId,1,8)) 
     END) AS Prime,
    (CASE WHEN substring(A.PrdAcctId,1,8)='20060003' 
            THEN count(substring(A.PrdAcctId,1,8)) 
     END) AS Sipsaviya,
    (CASE WHEN substring(A.PrdAcctId,1,8)='20060004' 
            THEN count(substring(A.PrdAcctId,1,8)) 
     END) AS Yalu,
    (CASE WHEN substring(A.PrdAcctId,1,8)='20060007' 
            THEN count(substring(A.PrdAcctId,1,8)) 
     END) AS Company,
    SUM(substring(A.PrdAcctId,1,8)) AS AccTotal 
FROM 
    D009022 A
WHERE 
    A.AcctStat<>3 AND
    substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)='20060000'
    OR substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)='20060001'
    OR substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)='20060002'
    OR substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)='20060003'
    OR substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)='20060004'
    OR substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)='20060007'
GROUP BY 
    A.LBrCode, substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)
ORDER BY 
    A.LBrCode, substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)
```

But it shows like this.

```
BranchCode BranchName ProductCode Miulasi Piri Prime Sipsaviya Yalu Company Acc
    1      City       20060000    5298                                      5298
    1      City       20060001            20                                20
    1      City       20060002                 477                          477
```

How is it possible to show results per `BranchCode`? Like per Branch only one row.

Comment: How about just using `GROUP BY A.LBrCode` ?

Comment: It says PrdAcctId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function

Comment: That's not possible if you also want to select non-count columns. Imagine you would get only one record per LBrCode if you grouped just by that. How would you retrieve branch name and product id. Is there one-to-one mapping between BrnachCode, BranchName and ProductCode? If yes, then why bother about grouping just by LbrCode!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work.
You can write Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) in MAX() function as it is unique for each code. Since MAX(10)=10 so it doesn't change the output.

```
   SELECT A.LBrCode                         AS BranchCode,
   (SELECT B.Name
    FROM   D001003 B
    WHERE  A.LBrCode = B.PBrCode
   )    AS BranchName,
   MAX(Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8))      AS ProductCode,
   Count(CASE
           WHEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) = '20060000' THEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)
         END)                        AS Miulasi,
   Count(CASE
           WHEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) = '20060001' THEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)
         END)                        AS Piripun,
   Count(CASE
           WHEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) = '20060002' THEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)
         END)                        AS Prime,
   Count(CASE
           WHEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) = '20060003' THEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)
         END)                        AS Sipsaviya,
   Count(CASE
           WHEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) = '20060004' THEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)
         END)                        AS Yalu,
   Count(CASE
           WHEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) = '20060007' THEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)
         END)                        AS Company,
   Sum(Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)) AS AccTotal 
FROM   D009022 A
WHERE  A.AcctStat <> 3
   AND Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) IN ( '20060000', '20060001', '20060002','20060003','20060004', '20060007' )
GROUP  BY A.LBrCode
ORDER  BY A.LBrCode
```

Answer (score 0):

`Count` should come on top of `case` statement

```
SELECT A.LBrCode                         AS BranchCode,
       (SELECT B.Name
        FROM   D001003 B
        WHERE  A.LBrCode = B.PBrCode)    AS BranchName,
       Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)      AS ProductCode,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) = '20060000' THEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)
             END)                        AS Miulasi,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) = '20060001' THEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)
             END)                        AS Piripun,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) = '20060002' THEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)
             END)                        AS Prime,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) = '20060003' THEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)
             END)                        AS Sipsaviya,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) = '20060004' THEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)
             END)                        AS Yalu,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) = '20060007' THEN Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)
             END)                        AS Company,
       Sum(Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)) AS AccTotal
FROM   D009022 A
WHERE  A.AcctStat <> 3
       AND Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) IN ( '20060000', '20060001', '20060002', '20060003',
                                             '20060004', '20060007' )
GROUP  BY A.LBrCode,
          Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)
ORDER  BY A.LBrCode,
          Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)
```

This one is more readable

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT A.LBrCode                      AS BranchCode,
                (SELECT B.Name
                 FROM   D001003 B
                 WHERE  A.LBrCode = B.PBrCode) AS BranchName,
                Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8)   AS ProductCode,
                A.PrdAcctId
         FROM   D009022 A
         WHERE  A.AcctStat <> 3
                AND Substring(A.PrdAcctId, 1, 8) IN ( '20060000', '20060001', '20060002', '20060003',
                                                      '20060004', '20060007' ))
SELECT BranchCode,
       BranchName,
       ProductCode,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN ProductCode = '20060000' THEN ProductCode
             END)     AS Miulasi,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN ProductCode = '20060001' THEN ProductCode
             END)     AS Piripun,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN ProductCode = '20060002' THEN ProductCode
             END)     AS Prime,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN ProductCode = '20060003' THEN ProductCode
             END)     AS Sipsaviya,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN ProductCode = '20060004' THEN ProductCode
             END)     AS Yalu,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN ProductCode = '20060007' THEN ProductCode
             END)     AS Company,
       Sum(ProductCode) AS AccTotal
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY LBrCode,
          BranchName,
          ProductCode
ORDER  BY LBrCode,
          ProductCode
```

Comment: is there anyway where i can group by only LBrCode?

Comment: @DeEDEe - Then you need to remove `ProductCode` from `select`